# mysql updating one column to another column in a different table

Tags: mysql

I have a script that updates a table with infomation and I want to update another table with some of it.

In **Table: products** I have a column called **last_updated** and I want that info to be copied into **Table: products_booze** which also has a column called **last_updated**

Any help would be great!

Comment: To which columns are tables related? What do you mean by `some of it`? Please give sample data of both the tables and your expected output based on that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide more details. Nobody can provide you with SQL commands unless you at least provide the schema for the 2 tables involved. For more information you can read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: how both table table is related?

Comment: products
Column Type Null Default  Comments
prod_id  varchar(255) No      
id  int(11) No      
url  varchar(255) No      
name  varchar(255) Yes  NULL    
cat  varchar(255) Yes  NULL    
img  varchar(255) Yes  NULL    
last_changed  datetime Yes  NULL    
cron  varchar(255) Yes  NULL    
promo  varchar(255) Yes  NULL

Comment: ok both tables are the same.. one is updated and one is not. the scraper data is put in the products table.. however I use the other table for part of the data from products and I just need it to copy over to ther other table.

Answer (score 0):

following SQL will do the trick

```
update products_booze, products 
SET products_booze.last_updated = products.last_updated
WHERE products_booze.prod_id = products.prod_id
```

Comment: is there a way to add that to a php script to cron to run? or maybe add it to my update.php script to run at the end?